# Improper integral of $\frac{1}{x} \sin \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: improper-integrals

Let $f(x)= \frac{1}{x} \sin \frac{1}{x}$ when $x \in (0, 1]$and $f(0)=0$. Prove that $\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx$ exists.

Can someone give me a hint to solution?

Comment: @Hippalectryon Really?

Comment: @zhw. Sorry I'm tired :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Make the change of variable $x = 1/y.$

Comment: Transforms to $\int_1^{\infty} \sin x / x dx < \infty$ +1

Comment: Oh, thanks xD I see